# If someone say"I'm hanging out in the woods trying to find you a gig",what does he mean?

Tags: meaning

-What are you, the lost Gabor sister?

-You should be walking around with a boa and a Pomeranian.

- Someone's crabby. - I'm not crabby.

-I'm hanging out in the woods trying to find you a gig.

Comment: Could you please provide the source?  It sounds like sarcasm, but without more information I can't tell you what's going on.

Comment: It's a conversation between an agent and his client,and the agent is busy finding  a chance for his client,but the client is just hanging our ,so he said this sentence.

Comment: The way you've formatted this makes it difficult to know who is talking.  Could you please label each line as either "agent" or "client"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which part of the sentence you're asking about. "The woods" could be a hyperbolic metaphor as in, "I've looked everywhere and now I've resorted to looking in the woods." (As in the middle of nowhere, the boonies.)